# Probability of winning X games in a tournament before Y losses occur

Tags: probability

Simply put, a prize tournament allows me to play as many matches as I want until I reach 3 match losses. Prizes are awarded based on the total number of wins when the tournament is over (i.e., after my 3rd loss). To estimate the difficulty of getting each prize, I would like to calculate my probability (or odds?) of winning 1,2,3,...,X matches before I lose for the 3rd time. My probability of winning a match is 55%. For the sake of argument, let's assume that my opponents will all have the same probability of winning (60%). There are no draws, and the order of wins/losses does not matter, except that the last match must be my 3rd loss.

To complicate things, how would the calculations change if each match was played as a best-of-3 against the same opponent?

My maths and stats are not very good, so I am afraid I am not sure where to start to approach this problem. I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through the calculations for the following problem, so I can understand what is going on.

**UPDATE:** after the suggestion of trying negative binomial, I have found that it could be what I am looking for, but I am confused about the use of terminology across different sources (e.g. what should be my k, r, and n). Lacking a math background, I have tried to put together a quick [Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CP9s.png) using the NEGBINOM.DIST function in Excel (God bless it). However, that still requires me to know what I am doing, which I don't. Would any kind soul be able to review the [Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CP9s.png) and advise what probability column should be correct for the given number of wins before 3 losses (using a p=0.5)?

Comment: I don't understand your "my opponents will all have the same probability of winning (60%)" ; indeed, if you have a winning probability of 55%, your opponents should logically have a winning probability equal to 45%...

Comment: @JeanMarie apologies, maybe I got confused there. Basically, each player will have a different winning **rate**. Mine is 55% but someone else could have a different one. I assumed that would translate to probability. If that's not the case, then I suppose that I can either win or lose a match, so my p would be 50%?

Comment: You would probably find the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) useful to you for this situation.

Comment: @Kman3 thanks, that seems to be the right direction. However, the first and second sentences of the article contradict each other on the definition of r. As I mentioned I am also oblivious of any stats (and most maths), so a mathematical article is hard to follow. To complicate things, there appear to be multiple definitions of a negative binomial distribution?? (section 1.3).
I have given it a go in Excel and will add some possible solutions to my original message.

Comment: To review your updated excel table, clearly the 2nd column should be correct, as there shouldn't be a "!NUM" anywhere in this calculation. (It seems like you're using P(win)$=1/2$, and that your second column actually calculates [1 - (the CDF of $NB(3, 1/2)$]. For example, P(0 win before 3 losses)$ = 1/8$, so your first row is  $ 1 - 1/8 = 87.5%$; P(1 win before 3 losses)$ = 3/16$, so your second row is $1 - 1/8 - 3/16 = 0.6875\approx 68.8\%$.)

Comment: @BenjaminWang you are right, forgot to mention that I had to use 1-NEGBNOM.DIST to get numbers that actually made sense. I think it's because the negative distribution aims at calculating the probability of failures, whereas I want the probability of success? I wonder if the a binomial distribution would be better for the purpose.

Comment: NegBin is fine. To get the probability mass function, take consecutive differences of the cumulative mass function (also known as the distribution), like $P(X=x)=P(X\le x)-P(X\le x-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the probability that you win each game is $w$. Then the probability that you will lose the third time on your $n$th game can be modeled by the **negative binomial distribution** I mentioned:

$${n-1 \choose 2}w^{n-3}(1-w)^3 = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}w^{n-3}(1-w)^3$$

If you win $50\%$ of the time, you're most likely to play $4$ to $5$ games; if you win $80\%$ of the time, you're most likely to play $10$ to $11$ games.

Comment: Thank you for the formula. So, assuming w=0.5 and n=5 (i.e., 2 games won before losing 3), the resulting probability should be P(2 out of 5)=18.75%. If so, that is where I get confused. I would expect the probability of winning 2 games out of 5 to be higher than that so, in the Excel table mentioned in my update, I have used [1- P(2 out of 5)] as Benjamin spotted in the comments. However, P(2 out of 5) works out at 50% in my calculations...

Comment: @Fraxav One alternative way you can think about it is by counting what we call **sample points** in statistics: if each game can either be won (W) or lost (L), then there are $2^5=32$ combinations of W's and L's. And we need a third L at the end, so we are essentially arranging $2$ L's and $2$ W's, which can happen a total of ${4 \choose 2} =6$ ways. So $\frac{6}{32}=0.1875=18.75\%$. It makes sense when you realize there are other possible outcomes (such as winning $5$ games) that have their own probabilities, but we would expect with a $50\%$ win rate to win $2.5$ out of $5$ games on average.